# How to use bash $variable inside cat <<EOF > Test.html

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I am faceing an issue when I want to use variable inside  `cat <<EOF > Test.html`  , for example

```
cat <<EOF > Test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

*/:root{--blue:#007


etc ..

Then 

<!-- Heading -->

<span class="h2 mb-0">

 $Test

</span>

</div>

   
etc ..
                
EOF
```

The `$Test` is not active I mean Bash considered it as a string not variable ( please find attached file )

[variable `$Test`  in brown color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKOog.jpg)

Comment: looks like homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add escape as shown below:

```
cat <<\EOF > Test.html
echo $var
EOF
```

Check the output by `cat Test.html`.

Comment: Awesome it worked !! :)